# Proving the square formed by pairs of lines

Tags: analytic-geometry

Show that the two pairs of lines $12x^2+7xy-12y^2=0, 12x^2+7xy-12y^2-x+7y-1=0$ form a square.
I know that both the equations represent a pair of straight lines. Also the first equation represents a pair of straight lines through origin which are as follows
$(4x-3y)(3x+4y)=0$
But how should I calculate for the second equation and after calculating how should I prove.

Comment: Working on the assumption that the second equation represents a pair of lines parallel to the first pair, you could try factorising the expression as $(4x-3y+a)(3x+4y+b)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The second pair of equations can be factored as (4x-3y+1)(3x+4y-1)

Thus, you have two pairs of parallel lines-

Pair 1: 4x-3y=0 and 4x-3y+1=0
Pair 2: 3x+4y=0 and 3x+4y-1=0

Two pairs of parallel lines intersect to make a square! Hope this helps :)